# How to remove some content after the window opens in Nuxt.js? Is it possible?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Acomponent />
        <Bcomponent />
        <div @click="openWindow()">hellow</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    methods: {
        openWindow() {
            const width = '1000'
            const height = '600'

            const left = Math.ceil((window.screen.width - width) / 2)
            const top = Math.ceil((window.screen.height - height) / 2)
            window.open(location.href, `width=${width}, height=${height}, left=${left}, top=${top}, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes`)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I hope that after the new window opens, Components A and B will not be seen in the new window. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a new attribute in data, default true, and in method openWindow(), set the attribute to false.

In the A and B components, put v-if="this.yourattribute".